# How do I create parameter Encoding in Alamofire 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

```
private func getEncoding() -> ParameterEncoding {
   if settings.method == Endpoint.Method.get {
         return ParameterEncoding.encode(URL)
   } else {
         return ParameterEncoding.encode(JSON)
   }
}
```

Comment: You can do a simple request like this. :
JSON encoding : Alamofire.request("RequestURL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
URL encoding : Alamofire.request("RequestURL", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)

Comment: But if We are calling a function for the method Type - Like                                              private func getMethod() -> Alamofire.HTTPMethod {
            
            if let method = self.settings.method {
                
                return method.toAFMethod()
                
            } else {
                
                return Alamofire.HTTPMethod.get
            }
        }                                                                                         Still getting the Error Extra argument in the Call